# setting up and using combo boxes in access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am new to access and this is my first database that I have built on my own.

I have two tables:

```
Site_ID
---------
EMS_ID (PK)
SITE_LOC

WaterSampleData
---------
SampleID (PK)
EMS_ID
SampleDate
SamplePeriod
<other columns>
```

and I have established a 1 to many relationship based on the EMS_ID field.  In the Site_ID table I have a field with the EMS_ID (primary key) which is a numerical value and a `SITE_LOC` field that is the text name of the sample location (as well as other information about the individual sites such as lat and long and so on).  In the WaterSampleData table I have the `SampleID` (primary key) `EMS_ID`, `SampleDate`, `SamplePeriod` and then fields for the different parameters that are collected.

I would like to set up a form for the technician to enter the water sample data to populate the table.  On the form I have the `EMS_ID` field set up as a combo box.  When I open the form view, a dropdown arrow appears in the box beside `EMS_ID` and the different values that are in the `SITE_ID` table are available for the user to select. That works fine.

The next field that I have is the `SITE_LOC` and I have also set this as a combo box.  When I open the form view, there is a drop down arrow but if I click on it there are no values listed.  However, when I select an `EMS_ID` from the field above it will populate the `SITE_LOC` field with the correct name that corresponds to the `EMS_ID`.

The form works for all intents and purposes but what I would like is to have the option for the technician to enter the sample data by either selecting the `EMS_ID` or the `SITE_LOC`  value and then have the corresponding value be automatically populated.  In other words, I want it to work both ways. As it stands I can select the `EMS_ID` and get the correct `SITE_LOC` but I want the option to select the `SITE_LOC` from the list of values in the `SITE_ID` table and have the `EMS_ID` value populated.
How do I do this? Is it possible?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your form set up with a Form/Subform?

Comment: Why not display both values in the first combobox?